# Properly using www-data to add/edit/remove safely

Tags: lamp, www-data

After building a LAMP stack, it's my understanding that `Apache` creates a `www-data` user. But you can't directly log in as `www-data` (security reasons). Instead, if you want to do something as `www-data` then you have to run this:

`su -s /bin/bash www-data`

I can live with that. But I have 2 questions:

1. What do you do, when you want to upload files via FTP? Currently, I have to FTP as a root user and then `chown` the files back to `www-data` after the upload. I run Magento, and that setup insists that I only give the `owner` permissions to `write`. Otherwise, I'd just give `write` access to `group`.
2. What do you do, when you want to allow a non-root user to `su` as `www-data`? Because if you run `su -s /bin/bash www-data` as a normal user, then they see `This account is currently not available`.

Comment: `www-data` is the default user for the Debian/Ubuntu packages. RHEL/CentOS uses a user called `apache`. Apache httpd lets you configure this how you want, and the distros have significantly different default configs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> it's my understanding that Apache creates a www-data user

No. Most package management systems will create a user when deploying the software.

> you can't directly log in as [that user]

Yes - as you say that's commonly done for security reasons.

> you have to ... su -s /bin/bash www-data

If the system is configured in such a way as to allow this - sometimes even this is disabled.

> What do you do, when you want to upload files via FTP?

You work out a permissions model which allows the relevant users to deploy and modify files and the webserver uid to read those files. In *very* rare and controlled cases you configure locations outside the document root the webserver uid can write to.

On every webserver I have configured, the webserver uid is the least privileged account, so I've granted it read access via the "other" permission slot, e.g.

```
  colin@animal /var/www/html $ ls -l
  total 28
  -rw-rw-r-- 1 colin webdev  11321 Dec 27  2016 index.html
  drwxrwsr-x 2 colin webdev   4096 Jan 10  2017 session
  -rw-rw-r-- 1 colin webdev    148 Feb 18  2018 login.php
  drwxrwsr-- 1 colin grafx    4096 Jan  9  2017 images
  -rw-rw-r-- 1 colin grafx    8334 Jul  4 21:59 logo.png
```

Permissions are the means by which you **share** access, not deny access.

> allow a non-root user to su as www-data

I don't. It should never be necessary.